# Tidying dataframe with repetitive cells and using 1 row as headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe, `df` that looks like this:

```
Year Country   C    D
1989   dd   12   6
1990   dd   15   6.5
1991   dd   75   9.3
1992   dd   88   10.2
1993   dd   98   11.1
```

(data goes on until country `zz, zz, zz` etc)

I want to have a data like this instead:

```
Country  1989  1990  1991  1992  1993
dd        6    6.5     9.3   10.2  11.1
```

(until `'zz'`)
I used this:

```
df.sort_index(df['Year'], ascending=False)
```

but doesn't give me what i wanted

(Please note that not all succeeding `'country'` have `'Year'` same as `'dd'`. Some may not have `1990` etc